# How to get Cogntio data from event in Lambda with Nodejs and Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services

```
import { APIGatewayEventDefaultAuthorizerContext, APIGatewayProxyEvent, any } from 'aws-lambda';

export async function myHandler(event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: APIGatewayEventDefaultAuthorizerContext,): Promise<any> {
  console.log(event, context);
  let cognitoIdentityId = event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId;
  let cognitoIdentity = event.requestContext.authorizer.claims.sub;
  return true;
}

export default myHandler;
```

I need to get the `cognitoIdentityId` from `event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId` and `Cognito sub` from `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims.sub`.
But putting it in a function like this:

```
  let cognitoIdentityId = event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId;
  let cognitoIdentity = event.requestContext.authorizer.claims.sub;
```

raises an Error that
`Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.`

Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: It is just a regular Lambda with HTTP endpoint.

Comment: Sorry - I misread this and thought you were talking about [Cognito Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) and you're not.

Answer (score 0):

This a TypeScript error because `authorizer` is possibly undefined (see the [note on the type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/common/api-gateway.d.ts#L25-L30)). To get around this, check for null/undefined, e.g. using the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):  `event.requestContext.authorizer?.jwt.claims.sub`